# Will VLC from the Software Center receive the same updates as the stable PPA?

Tags: 12.04, updates, ppa, vlc, stable-release-updates

[VLC 2.1.0](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.1.0.html) has been released. My computer runs 12.04 and the lastet VLC version is currently 2.0.8.

Will the VLC 2.1.0 update be availabe for me as well (with a slight delay maybe), or is it recommended to add the **ppa:videolan/stable-daily** ppa to receive updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical will usually backport security updates to the default repositories. If you want the features coming with the latest releases and are willing to take the risks involved, use the PPA.

The software center will install and update the most recent package version from all enabled repositories and PPAs.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. So you imply that adding the ppa would not be necessary, right?

Comment: Yes, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The software center will install and update the most recent package version from all enables repositories and PPAs.

Comment: In its current format, your answer does not yet explain if adding the stable VLC PPA is neccessary (which is my question).

Comment: yea,it's not necessary.........

Answer (score 0):

2.0.8 update is now available in Ubuntu archives for P-Q-R, whereas I have to tell 2.1.0 will not get into 13.04 (not worth exception for feature freeze-Debian did not update VLC to even this version, it was still 2.0.3 in wheezy when I wrote this.) So upgrading Ubuntu to 13.10 right after being out is the best choice considering the other security patches(Ubuntu regular releases now get 9 months of support, and the support is minimal after first 6 months-sometimes you will not see an update for a week even if you check everyday-LTS releases are different story).